# Chain this jquery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to chain this jQuery expression or improve it? All i really want to do is change "my text" to "new text".

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   my text
  <span>button 1</span>
  <span>button 2</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = $("#myDiv");
var buttons = element.children().detach();
element.text("new Text");
element.append(buttons);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = $("#myDiv");
var buttons = element.children().detach();
element.text("new Text").append(buttons);
```

Should work fine! You can always chain methods, that use the same selector.

Answer (score 2):

`.contents()` gets all of the child nodes including text nodes. Get the first node and change the `textContent` property.

```
$('#myDiv').contents()[0].textContent = "new text";
```

if you need to get more complicated you may want to look at [Karl Swedberg's Text Children plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/textchildren/), which provides various different options too.

jQuery is primarily focused on manipulating element nodes (`nodeType` 1) and not too great a manipulating text nodes outside the context of element nodes. Sometimes the best way is to drop down to "raw JavaScript" :)

Comment: i like your solution, but i'm worried about browser support for textContent vs innetText.

Comment: (+1)  anyway. I might use something like this for retrieving text var text = x.innerText || x.textContent

Comment: yeah, you'll need to iron that one out too :)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to wrap my text with a span. Then you can do `$('#myDiv span').first().text('new text');`

As for chaining:

This works:

```
var element = $("#myDiv");
var buttons = element.children().detach();
element.text("new Text").append(buttons);
```

Comment: @Razor Storm - Your first answer will change the text of both `<span>` elements that have button text in them too.

Comment: Oops, I changed my answer to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

No need to bother jQuery at all... plain JavaScript is much quicker for simple tasks as this.

```
var element =  document.getElementById('myDiv');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('my text','new text');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xAhA6/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a plugin to do what you want:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.changeText = function(newText) {

    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var divs = element.children().detach();
        element.text(newText).append(divs);
    });
 };
})(jQuery);

//use it like so:
$('#myDiv').changeText('new text');
```

Then you can chain other methods to that if you want to continue to manipulate `$('#myDiv')`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DQtjE/

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the text in a `<p>`? Then you would only need:

`$("#myDiv p").text("new Text");`